# MATLAB: Use a variable with a file extenstion to load files

Tags: matlab, variables, load

I am using MATLAB

I Have 51 files in their own directory all of `.out` extention created by a seperate program, all numbered `0` to `50`.

ie

```
0.out
1.out
2.out
```

and so on til `50.out`.

I need to load each file 1 by one to do calculations upon them within a for loop. How would I do this using the count variable to load the file, if the directory is set beforehand?

i.e.

```
%set directiory
cd(......)

%for loop
For count = 0:50,
     data = count.out     *<-----this line* 
     .....
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

First generate the file name with

```
fileName = [int2str(count) '.out'];
```

then open the file with

```
fid = fopen(fileName, 'r');
```

The loading phase depends on the kind of file you want to read. Assuming it is a text file you can, for example, read it line after line with

```
while ~feof(fid)
    line = fgetl(fid);
end
```

or use more specialized functions (see http://www.mathworks.it/it/help/matlab/text-files.html). Before the end of the `for` loop you'll have to close the file by calling

```
fclose(fid);
```

Answer (score 0):

Another quite nice way to do it is to use the dir function

http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/dir.html

a = dir('c:\docs*.out')

Will give you a structure containing all the info about the *.out files in the directory you point it to, (or the path). You can then loop through it bit by bit. using fopen or csvread or whatever file reading function you want to use.